# Multiple LEFT OUTER JOIN on multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to convert the following Oracle SQL query syntax (Use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `(+)`):

```
SELECT      *
FROM        TABLEA A, TABLEB B, TABLEC C, TABLED D
WHERE       MY_COL = @col_val
AND         A.X = B.X(+)
AND         B.Y = C.Y(+)
AND         D.Z=A.Z
```

Here is what I tried so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLEA A, TABLEB B, TABLEC C, TABLED D
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLEA A ON A.X = B.X
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLEC C ON B.Y = C.Y
WHERE MY_COL = @col_val
AND D.Z = A.Z;
```

But I get the error :

> "ORA-00904: "B"."X" : invalid identifier"

Comment: if you tag of dbms is oracle, then `@` couldn't be the sign of assignment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `join` on `D` is an inner join, the rest are left outer joins:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLEA A JOIN
     TABLED D
     ON D.Z = A.Z LEFT JOIN
     TABLEB B
     ON A.X = B.X LEFT JOIN
     TABLEC C
     ON B.Y = C.Y 
WHERE MY_COL = @col_val;
```

I always start chains of joins with inner joins followed by the `left outer join`.  I never use `right join`, and `full join` rather rarely.  The inner joins define the rows in the result set, so they come first.

Comment: Only one point Gordon, if @Platus wanted to maintain the implied order of the columns, he'd have to `SELECT a.*, b.*, c.*, d.* FROM...` - it depends on how faithfully he needs to reproduce the original query, he doesn't indicate whether column order is relevant. And as you say, `RIGHT JOIN` is the rarest beast - I think so consistently from left to right in constructing a query, that I struggle to visualise it's effects!

Answer (score 3):

You don't should mix explicit and implicit sintax

```
  SELECT *
  FROM TABLEA A 
  INNER JOIN TABLEL L ON L.Z = A.Z
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLEB B ON A.X = B.X
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLEC C ON B.Y = C.Y
  WHERE A.MY_COL = @col_val
```

you should use inner join (or join) for TABLEL

Comment: Thanks but what about TABLEB, don't I need to mention it somewhere?

Comment: answer  updated ..     ...the second  tableA is TABLEB

Comment: typo, line 3 should say "A.Z" not "U.Z". Also no semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLEA A
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLEB B ON A.X = B.X
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLEC C ON B.Y = C.Y
INNER JOIN TABLED D ON D.Z = A.Z
WHERE MY_COL = @col_val
```

`TABLEB` and `TABLEC` goes in `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (you have used +), instead `TABLED` goes in `INNER JOIN`